# Xamarin "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements"

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I want to test my created iOS app on my iPhone. The build was successful but while xamarin studio tries to transfer the file via usb to my iPhone i got the following error:

```
VerifyingApplication: 70%
  PercentComplete: 40
  Status: VerifyingApplication
 ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.yNZx88/extracted/<APPName>.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/<NAME>/Projects/<APPName>/<APPName>/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.2-10.2.1/<APPNamr>.app' on the device '<DEVICEName>': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).
--- inner exception
Xamarin.Installation.FailedInstallException: Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016)

[...]

Application could not be uploaded to the device.
```

I'm new to xamarin and don't know what to do. A apple developer account is available and the certificate and provisioning Profile are created. The phone is added to device list and a identifier is are created.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you added the device to the provisioning profile? (I think it should be done, I haven't touched it a lot of time)

Comment: did you check the iOS Device log as suggested?

Comment: @Yitschak yes, the device is added to the provisoning profile..

Comment: @Jason Where can I check the log from the device?

Comment: use XCode to view logs

Comment: There are no logs or erros for that

Comment: @Jason - NOT the logs in XCode - those are *crash* logs. He needs to look at a live log stream while the app is attempting to install. But thank you for trying to help - that motivated me to add an answer to explain that, and other possible steps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

First, make sure both Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac are updated to latest versions. If you update Xcode, open it. Sign in. If it asks to "Install additional required components?", pick "Install". Then re-open the updated VS.

With newer Visual Studio for Mac and Xcode, you might have all the info you need in the "Deploying to Device" tab that appears when you launch to phone (from VS) a Debug | iPhone version of your app. Scroll to bottom of that tab, look for a message like:

> ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of ... (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
>
> ... Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

In some situations, the instructions below won't give you any more useful detail than the above. For example, I'm not seeing (even in iOS Device Log) *which* entitlement is failing; I had to fix the above by comparing the entitlements my app had checked in `info.plist`, with the certificate I was using. If in doubt, try *unchecking* all entitlements in `info.plist`. Deploy again. (Obviously any functionality that needs the entitlement won't work, but at least you can verify you are able to deploy without that error message.)

---

**Original answer:**

(Regarding comments on the question) What you need is NOT the logs in Xcode - those are *crash* logs. What is needed here is in Xamarin / View / **Pads / "Device Log"**. *While installing the app, messages will scroll by*.

**Open the Device Log pad *before* starting the install** - it is a dynamic display of messages from your phone. Select your phone from the dropdown list at top left of pad. (At any time, click eraser icon at top right of pad, to clear the old messages.)

If many messages are scrolling by, then click on the i-inside-blue-circle icon (tooltip "Show Messages") (unselect it) to hide the Info messages. Make sure that x-in-red-circle icon (tooltip "Show Errors") is selected.

After the install fails, "select all / copy / paste" into a text editor. Search for the install failure. Immediately before it should be some lines that give more information.  Specifically, it will clarify which of these two possibilities is the problem: 1) *entitlements* or 2) something about *device*.

I'll bet its *entitlements*. You'll need to isolate what entitlement is causing the problem. Are you using *Push Notifications*? *iCloud*? Those are likely culprits. Or perhaps one of the *privacy* related entitlements - make sure you are following current instructions for the latest iOS version: new privacy settings were added in iOS 10, then 12, then 13 (IIRC).

Look at source code of `Entitlements.plist`.  Save a copy of that somewhere away from your project.  Start with a blank (empty) `Entitlements.plist`. [Add an empty text file with that name, if you don't have it in your project folder.]  Are you then able to deploy to phone?

Of course, you won't be able to *use* the entitlements you need, while this is blank, but you should be able to get the first screen of your app up, or at least some Apple dialog asking user if they want to allow ..whatever entitlement you needed..

Then add to `Entitlements.plist` until you can't deploy. Then Google for that specific problem - hopefully there is a solution out there.

---

Another possibility is that your **provisioning profile** lacks an entitlement that you are asking for. Go back to Apple developer website, where your certificates and provisioning profiles are listed. Select the prov. profile you are using. Under "Enabled Services", make sure it lists the services you are using.
(Some Apple features don't require specific entitlements; if in doubt, create a new provisioning profile, and look carefully at all the options for entitlements, for any feature you are using.)

Comment: Nice tipps!  I will try it next time. I fixed it by create a new project and add all old files. after that it worked fine. I have no idea why...

Comment: Thanks a lot the Pad/Device Log tip really helped :)

Comment: Okay, this solved my problem. Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: Where is the "Enabled Services" you speak of? I found the Edit button, I have Push Notifications enabled but app still doesn't work

Comment: @Gerry - Currently the steps are: At Apple Developer website, in Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles, At left side select Profiles. In list, select the profile you want to examine. Now, near middle of screen, is a section "Enabled Capabilities". You should see "Push Notifications" there. If so, search for other questions and look at the answers. If still stuck, google 'github xamarin ios push notification example'. Download an example project, try to get it to work. Be persistent; it is difficult to get this to work when nothing happens, so there is no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 28):

If your provisions were working before you added and set your "Entitlements.plist" (for example for Icloud) then:

You need to remove the "Entitlements.plist" from your configuration.

Project Option >  IOS Bundle Signing > Custom Entitlements (Keep it blank).

Comment: I wasted few hours trying to figure out and this helped. I wonder why Entitlements.plist doesn't work as a value when I obviously selected it from the list and the file is there, suggesting it's already used.

Comment: I also had the same issue,error while installing app,wasted many hours;this solution made it right

Answer (score 4):

This fix for me :

1. Right click on IOS Project and click on Options
2. If you see under Custom Entitlements: Info.plist then change it to Entitlements.plist
3. Compile project again and test it

Comment: Thanks so much!! I don't understand how the Info.plist got in there...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I tried to register for remote notifications iOS. I set the push notifications capabilities in my Entitlements.plist in Xamarin.iOS project, but systematically got this error:

`ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.vvvwk7/extracted/company.MyApp.Ios.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)`

My entitlements were set correctly, but The issue was that I was using a wilcard dev provisioning profile, which did not have the push notifications capabilities in Apple developer portal.
I had to change to a development provisioning profil, which I set Push notifications capabilities in apple developer portal, and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the app was running fine on my iPhone 12 Pro but when I tried to run it on an old iPad Air I got this error.  It turns out that I have more than one identifier in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list and I had configured the iPad with the wrong one.

Once I created a profile for the iPad in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list with the other identifier the error went away.

So to sum it up

- make sure that an identifier in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list is configured for the app you are running.  The App ID should match the Bundle Identifier in Info.plist.
- make sure your device is registered in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list.  Your device should be added here automatically when connected to a mac running Xcode but it can be added manually by copying the UDID from Xcode Window/Devices and Simulators.
- make sure there is a profile in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list that pairs the identifier and device from above