# Provisioning profile for Xamarin Forms iOS Extension

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi all I have created a service extension project in my Xamarin forms solution.

I have enabled App Groups in Entitlements.plist in both the extension project and the main iOS project (group.co.myco.myapp).

I'm getting the following error: Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension on iOS.
(OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension)

Do you know how this can be fixed?

**Update**

1. I have enabled App Groups and added group.co.myco.myapp on the provisioning profile for my app.
2. I have created a new identifier (App ID) co.myco.myapp.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension
3. I have also created a new provisioning profile for co.myco.myapp.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension and enabled app groups with the same group name as (1)
4. Project builds, but when deploying to the device I get the following errors:

(The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)

Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

Is there anythig else that can be tried?

**Update 2**
There was an empty string in the Entitlements file. after removing that it worked.

Comment: Does the main iOS project build, but the extension does not? I haven't made a service extension project - does it contain an info.plist? **If so:** **in VS Mac**: open info.plist, Application tab, click "Automatic Provisioning". Follow instructions. OR **in VS Windows**: Automatic Provisioning is found in YourApp.iOS / Properties / iOS Bundle Signing. Select **team**. THEN If the problem is when **attaching a device**, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327393/199364).

Comment: Did you ever configure `App Groups` in Apple Developer site ?  You need to enable `App Groups` in Identifiers section and recreate your provisioning profile , download and reinstall .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I've enabled the App group and re-downloaded the provisioning profile. but still not working. I've add an app group in there (group.co.myapp) and re-downloaded the provisioning profile but it is still not working (same error no provisioning profile)

Comment: I've created a provisioning profile for the extension co.myco.myapp.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension and it seems to build. however getting an error with deployment to a test device:
(The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)

Comment: Looks like an empty string was in the Entitlements file causing the error. :-/