# Visual Studio/Xamarin on Windows doesn't see my Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile on the Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin. I've built a simple app in VS 2019 on Windows, which is paired to a Mac on our company network. I'm trying to deploy the app to an iPhone. I'm using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows). I've attached my iPhone to the Mac via cable, and created an XCode build scheme (XCode 13.3). My problem is when I get to the last section, Deploy your Xamarin.iOS app. I don't see (in VS on Windows) the Signing Identity or the Provisioning Profile that I created on the Mac in the XCode build scheme. I've verified that the keychain.app on the Mac contains the key I created. I have seen some comments on the web that I should delete the .mobileprovision files I find in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles but I'm hesitant to do that because I don't know what that I might do. So, 2 questions:

1. Could the .mobileprovision files be the problem? If I delete them, how do I recreate them?
2. Does anyone have any other suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Comment: You might need to use `Automatic Provisioning`. I do this first in VS Mac, then I connect phone directly to pc for `Automatic Provisioning` in VS Windows. Then I move phone back to Mac. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327393/199364).

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, as I understand it, I can't use Automatic Provisioning because I don't have an official developers account. I'm trying to use Free Provisioning. I've tried to go to VS on the Mac and use Manual Provisioning, but I don't know how to open the project I've created in XCode in VS, and if I try to create a new project in VS, it doesn't recognize the provisioning I've created in XCode. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve never tried free provisioning. In vs mac, create a project with exact same bundle id - for this test, doesn’t matter that it’s not same project, as long as bundle id is same - that will let you check if vs mac sees device.

Comment: VS does see my iPhone, but it doesn't see any Provisioning Profiles. I think I'm going to switch over to Swift....