# Can't build MAUI app for connected iPad, error message demands certificate

Tags: certificate, maui, digital-signature

1. I installed Visual Studio Mac v17.6.1 (build 452), on a MacBook pro running Ventura 13.4.1, with Xcode 14.3.1 present on the machine.
2. I auto-generated the simplest "Hello, World" MAUI app, with the dorky waving robot.
3. The MacCatalyst version of the app runs fine on the host MacBook. The iOS version runs fine on the iPad simulator on that same machine.
4. But when I directly connect a 7th generation iPad running iOS 16.5.1 with Debug settings enabled, and try to build a debug version for it, I encounter the error: "No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com".  The iOS bundle signing identity is set to "Developer(Automatic)".  I expected the iPad version to work seamlessly with Developer signing, as it does with the Mac and Simulator versions. Any idea how to get past this? Tx

Comment: Its been a few years, but see if [this xamarin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60327393/199364) still works. Skip the first bit about "entitlements", start at "provisioning". Personally, I always first make sure XCode can see the device, in its device list. There is a device provisioning option in XCode somewhere.