# Twilio video chat with 10s delay in android 5+

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, twilio

I'm developing a mobile application which implements peer to peer video chat using twilio (we are allowing only 2 participants in a given room)

The project is written in c# using Xamarin, so a binding is needed for the twilio sdk. 
I'm using this one as a base: https://github.com/dkornev/TwilioXamarinBindings , but I've built my own binding using the last version of the twilio sdk available now, which is the v4.2.0 (from here: https://bintray.com/twilio/releases/video-android/4.2.0)

Then, I've used the quickstart project provided by twilio: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android as the base for our project. I've added some animations to the VideoViews-translation and/or scaling, but that´s all.

The problem is that we've tested the video chat and there is a very noticeable delay in the remote video. The video is like 10 seconds behind, at all times, and even worse, it appears to be played in slow-motion (with time jumps every now and then).

The application is working fine when tested in android 5/5.1 though.

Any clue on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
-This delay can be observed using previous versions of twilio (even with v3.x.x)

-I've took off verything from the logic and the view and left only the connection logic + the VideoView for the remote video alone
No change so far.

Could it be related to the video codecs somehow?

**UPDATE2**
This video delay is happening in emulator with android 9 and in a physical phone with android 9 (which has hw support for H.264). The video can be seen nice, without any delay in emulator with android 5, and physical phones with android 5.1 and 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After far more than a week struggling with this issue, I've finally found what's happening (that doesn't mean that I know how to resolve the issue [yet]): We are using Layer to provide messaging functionality and Twilio for voice/video chat. Well, the video delay is caused by the interaction between those two libraries.
The delay in the video appears merely by instantiating the LayerClient. We don't need to register the client listeners (there are 3 of them: authentication, connection, sync), we do not need even to call the connect method to see this happening.
I'll update this answer if I found any permanent solution or at least a workaround

Comment: do you might to share some working sample code in xamarin form with twilio?

Comment: Hi @MinHongTan, I'm not using Forms in this project, it's just a Xamarin Android app.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you convert it from android sample to Xamarin android? because i'm a newbie in Xamarin.

Comment: do you able to share some code for your android? because i don't see any example for android.

Comment: Ok, so you just have to add your twilio video binding dll (I'm assuming you know what is a java binding in xamarin) and then you can write a xamarin test app following the official android example: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android 
As you may (o may not...) know, once you add the dll to your project, you can translate the java code to c# easily, it is [almost] a copy-paste task

Comment: Thanks Guillermo Gerard! I managed to code twilio in xamarin android. Alnost copy and paste. May i know is it the same for ios?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. 
No, it's not the same, for iOS you have this take a look at this example: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios

Comment: i'm using free apple id, i'm able to develop and deploy normal apps to ios device. but when i include twilio video. it show error "Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile".  is it because apple free id?

Comment: Hi @MinHongTan , It sounds like a problem in your xamarin/visual studio/Xcode setup. Check another posts about this matter, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906973/xamarin-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements

Comment: already found this solution. but no luck. not sure any other  possibility

Comment: i believe is provision profile issue. i'm using free account. will try to subscribe apple developer id.   twilio call can wakelock and show incoming call from background?