# iOS UNNotificationServiceExtension - how fix provisioning profiles issue?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin iOS app. I added UNNotificationServiceExtension for my app. And now I am getting the following error:

```
Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement 
not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current 
provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).
```

I am using separate IDs for my app and extension. also i created separate profiles for each id. only I remove the extension - then I can sign (deploy) my application.

This is  example my identifier:

```
app: com.my.testapp 
ext: com.my.testapp.NotifExt
```

Any advice - I would be very grateful

Comment: Make sure that the version of Xcode and VS are up to date . Here is a similar issue that maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906973/xamarin-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements

Comment: I will post it as answer with more details , could you accept it?which will help more people who has similar issue :)

Comment: yes. I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement
> not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current
> provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

The error always appears when we update the IDE . Actually , it is necessary to keep up to date between VS and Xcode .

In addition, the error also maybe caused by  that your provisioning profile lacks an entitlement that you are asking for.Login in  Apple developer account, where your certificates and provisioning profiles are listed. Select the **prov**. profile you are using. Under "**Enabled Services**", make sure it lists the services you are using.

For more details about the error you could refer [Xamarin "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906973/xamarin-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements) .